# JQUERY get data from <td> and <input> tag for every row and output on single line

Tags: jquery

Sorry, I am really green when it comes to JQUERY. I have the following html code, that basically makes a table with text using  and  checkboxes.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="table2CSV.js" > </script>
<script>
function getCSVData()
{
     var csv_value=$('#tblGrid').table2CSV({delivery:'value'});
     $("#csv_text").val(csv_value);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table>
   <tr>
     <td class="cellText">HB DIOCD - AR3 HT</td>
       <td width="60" align="center">
          <input class="chText" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="X" name="options" />
     </td>
        <td width="60" align="center">
           <input class="chText" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="X" name="options" />
      </td>
      <td width="60" align="center">
         <input class="chText" type="checkbox"  name="options"/>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table> 
<form action="getCSV.php" method ="post" >
<input type="hidden" name="csv_text" id="csv_text">
<input type="submit" value="Save Configuration" onclick="getCSVData()"></form>
</body>
</html>
```

The jquery code is next (found this code on the web,KunalBabre.com - table2CSV). It does a very good job when there is just text:

```
jQuery.fn.table2CSV = function(options) {
    var options = jQuery.extend({
        separator: ',',
        header: [],
        delivery: 'popup' // popup, value
    },
    options);

    var csvData = [];
    var headerArr = [];
    var el = this;

    //header
    var numCols = options.header.length;
    var tmpRow = []; // construct header avalible array

    if (numCols > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < numCols; i++) {

           tmpRow[tmpRow.length] = formatData(options.header[i]);
        }
    } else {
        $(el).filter(':visible').find('th').each(function() {
            if ($(this).css('display') != 'none') tmpRow[tmpRow.length] = formatData($(this).html());
        });
    }

   row2CSV(tmpRow);
    // actual data   
    $(el).find('tr').each(function() 
     {
        var tmpRow = [];
        var valArray=[];
        $(this).filter(':visible').find('td').each(function()
        {   
             if ($(this).css('display') != 'none') tmpRow[tmpRow.length] = formatData($(this).html());
   });        
       //alert(tmpRow);
       row2CSV(tmpRow);
   });
   if (options.delivery == 'popup') {
       var mydata = csvData.join('\n');
       return popup(mydata);
   } else {
       var mydata = csvData.join('\n');
       return mydata;
   }

    function row2CSV(tmpRow) {
        var tmp = tmpRow.join('') // to remove any blank rows
        // alert(tmp);
       if (tmpRow.length > 0 && tmp != '') {
           var mystr = tmpRow.join(options.separator);
           csvData[csvData.length] = mystr;
      }
  }
   function formatData(input) {
      // replace " with “
      var regexp = new RegExp(/["]/g);
      var output = input.replace(regexp, "“");
      //HTML
      var regexp = new RegExp(/\<[^\<]+\>/g);
          var output = output.replace(regexp, "");
       if (output == "") return '';
       return '"' + output + '"';
  }
  function popup(data) {
      var generator = window.open('', 'csv', 'height=400,width=600');
       generator.document.write('<html><head><title>CSV</title>');
       generator.document.write('</head><body >');
       generator.document.write('<textArea cols=70 rows=15 wrap="off" >');
       generator.document.write(data);
       generator.document.write('</textArea>');
       generator.document.write('</body></html>');
       generator.document.close();
       return true;
    }
};
```

The code when executed returns the data inside the  tag, but not the values inside of the  tag.

Here is a sample of the output:
"HB DIOCD - AR3 HT",,,

What I would like is:
"HB DIOCD - AR3 HT",X,X,

in the actual data portion of the script, I was successful getting the individual values from the input checkboxes, however I do not know how to get the  text concatenated with the  values.

Thanks for any help,

CPAZ

Comment: `returns the data inside the tag, but not the values inside of the tag.` "the data inside the tag" is ambiguous.

Answer (score 2):

Well your checkboxes have the save value, so won't be much use to you.  But regardless, you can do this:

```
var outputArr = [];

$('td').each(function() {
   output.push($(this).find('input').val() || $(this).text());
});

var output = outputArr.toString();
```

Comment: I did use your suggestion, it works like a charm. I made a few modifications..         var outputArr = [];   
        $(this).filter(':visible').find('td').each(function() 
        {
         outputArr.push($(this).find('input').val() || $(this).text());
        });
        tmpRow[tmpRow.length] = outputArr.toString();

Answer (score 0):

By giving the checkboxes names based on the celltext and wrapping the table in its own `<form id="myDummyForm">...</form>` tags, you could take advantage of jQuery's `$(formSelector).serialize()` to format `name=value` pairs into a string painlessly.

You could then do some simple(?) string handling to get the data in the format you want.

HTML :

```
<form id="myDummyForm">
<table>
   <tr>
     <td class="cellText">HB DIOCD - AR3 HT</td>
     <td width="60" align="center">
          <input class="chText" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="X" name="HB DIOCD_AR3_HT_1" />
     </td>
     <td width="60" align="center">
           <input class="chText" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="X" name="HB DIOCD_AR3_HT_2" />
     </td>
     <td width="60" align="center">
         <input class="chText" type="checkbox" name="HB DIOCD_AR3_HT_3"/>
     </td>
   </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Javascript :

```
jQuery.fn.table2CSV = function(options) {
    ...
    var arr = $("#myDummyForm").serialize().split('&');
    ...
};
```

Your javascript would thus be simplified but at the cost of more involved HTML.

With a little imagination, you could dynamically set the input's names (again using jQuery) to avoid having to do it manually (or procedurally if the page is built server-side).